# Rigging character while clothes hidden

Tags: rigging

When I rigged my character the clothes were hidden. Would I need apply automatic weights again while the clothes are visible? Or would the clothes move with mesh?

Comment: You have to assign the weights by select the mesh first then the armature, so if it was hidden it couldn't be selected, so you have to reassign it.

Comment: How do I reassign it? Is it the same process as rigging the mesh? Ctrl P Applying automatic weights?

Comment: Yes, I thought that.